# Entity Framework web.config connection string for IBM DB2 database

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4.1, db2

Have searched low and wide, and can't yet seem to locate a connection string for the web.config file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a IBM db2 driver:

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r5/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.swg.im.dbclient.adonet.doc/doc/c0054118.html

or you can use a oledb driver with is not very fast, for the connectionstring you can have a look at:

http://www.connectionstrings.com/ibm-db2

Answer (score 0):

What is the issue that you are facing? Are you not able to create conn string for given DB? Did you take a look at http://www.connectionstrings.com/?